# Git push and pull

Tags: gitlab

I have a git Repo, everything working good until when i  manually updated  the branch file in gitlab .I cannot push in to it anymore.
When i use git push origin master, i get your update rejected because your branch is behind. I should use git pull .

I tried updating using git pull origin master 
 i get your local changes to the following files will not be overwritten by merge. Please commit changes .
But when i use git commit -m "" , i get no changes to commit .

I would love to be able to push my updates to the branch file as usual.
I am new to git please help

Comment: Did you ever add your changes?

Comment: I have not had success , because when ever i try to push may changes  git push origin master, i get update rejected because my working branch behind. i use git pull to update my working branch, but does not update it .

Answer (score 2):

Try `git stash` to save your current changes in stash, then `git pull` to update from origin, then `git stash pop` to get back your changes, and then `git commit` and `git push`